# How to create an array and store in local storage using json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi guys so i have a form which takes in data like item name, code etc, so when i press the enter button...iv used json stringify and get an alert of what is stored in the local storage. However when i click reset and create a new item it just shows the new item, is there anyway i could store all my items created in local storage...? this is part of my coding. Im a beginner so please excuse if the question is too simple

Thanks

```
$('#myBox #EnterButton').click(function() {
    ItemData = { 
        'ItemCode' : $('#ItemCode').val(),
        'ItemName' : $('#ItemName').val()
    };

    localStorage.ItemData=JSON.stringify(ItemData);
    $('#myBox').slideUp();
});
```

...

```
$('#myBox2 #EnterButton').click(function() {
    if (localStorage.ItemData) {
        alert(localStorage.ItemData);
        ItemData = JSON.parse(localStorage.ItemData);
    }

    if (ItemData.ItemCode) {
        $('#myBox #ItemCode').val(ItemData.ItemCode);
    }

    if (ItemData.ItemName) {
        $('#myBox #ItemName').val(ItemData.ItemName);
    }
})
```

and i have declared itemdata as a public variable. Hope its clear. TIA

Comment: use localStorage.setItem('itemData', data) and localStorage.getItem('itemData')

Comment: Note that `ItemData = {}` is an object not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to organize the way ÿou are using localStorage (a getter/setter class might help with maintenance). From your code above, it seems you are always overriding **localStorage.ItemData** with the values just inserted.
The solution would be for localStorage.Items to be an array and whenever you insert in that array, iterate over it to see if it's not already added (based on itemCode for instance) and override or insert a new item.

I presume this is enough for playing around. A more advanced concept than localStorage and used for slightly different purpuses would be pouchdb - websql in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like if you want multiple items to be stored, you should be using an array of itemData objects.  You'll then have to parse this (array), and use something like Array.push(newItem) then stringify it again before saving it.

```
var allItems = localStorage.getItem('ItemData');
if(allItems == null) {
    localStorage.setItem('ItemData', JSON.stringify([ItemData]));
} else {
    allItems = JSON.parse(allItems);
    allItems.push(ItemData);
    localStorage.setItem('ItemData', JSON.stringify(allItems));
}
```